# Boolean expression ( 0 or None and False)

Tags: python, boolean-logic

Question: 0 or None and False

why it give me None as answer? I totally don't understand

I thought None and False should be False because none of them are True, but my python shell tell me it's None. Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this post helpful:

[External Discussion on SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1679008/non-true-false-and-or-principles-in-python)

Example:

```
None and False
>>> None

False and None
>>> False

0 or None
>>> None

None or 0
>>> 0
```

It has to do with the behavior of 'and', which checks the first argument before the second (called *short-circuit evaluation)*.

[Another resource about general boolean logic in Python.](https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/boolean.html)

Comment: That really makes sense thank you so much for your help!!!!